# Filter dataset to not show top rows by a column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

This is probably a easier one. (Preferable tidyverse solution)

Two questions
Q1. Why doesnt below give me top 4 rows by maximum Sepal.Length values

```
library(tidyverse)
1. iris %>% top_n(Sepal.Length,4)
```

Q2 I want to do the opposite of top_n, slice_max. I want to show the dataframe without the top n rows within a dataframe

```
library(tidyverse)
#something like below
iris %>% filter(!top_n(Sepal.Length,4))
```

The output for 1. should be 4 rows, the output of 2. should be 146 rows (150-4 rows by top Sepal.Length values without ties)

Comment: perhaps `iris %>% slice_max(order_by = Sepal.Length, n = 4)`

Comment: Yup works for 1. & for Q2?

Comment: For 2 `iris %>% filter(!Sepal.Length %in%  head(sort(unique(Sepal.Length), decreasing = FALSE), 4) )`

Comment: Thanks, & for Q2?  Any easier way?

Comment: For the duplicate cases, how do you want to handle

Comment: Basic solution: Without ties, whichever order it is, should remove 4 rows. Advanced: Give an option to select how can I handle ties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`slice` family of functions replaces the soon to be deprecated `top_n`.  Specify the column to be ordered in `order_by` and `n` in `slice_max`

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
      slice_max(order_by = Sepal.Length, n = 4)
```

By default, it uses `with_ties = TRUE`.  If we need to remove the ties, specify it as `FALSE`

---

For the second case, `setdiff` (there is a data.frame method in `dplyr`) can be used

```
iris %>% 
  slice_max(order_by = Sepal.Length, n = 4) %>% 
  setdiff(iris, .)
```

Or another option is to create a ranking with `dense_rank` and `filter` based on the rank

```
iris %>%
     filter(!dense_rank(-Sepal.Length) %in% 1:4)
```

If we want to only remove the 4 rows, then use `row_number`

```
iris %>%
    filter(!row_number(-Sepal.Length) %in% 1:4)
```

Or with `slice`

```
iris %>% 
    slice(setdiff(row_number(-Sepal.Length), 1:4))
```

Comment: I like the approach, only thing is I'd want to avoid hardcode iris in setdiff(). This is still the best solution I came across but I guess  there would be something which avoids hardcoding iris & do this in a simple as yours. Also, just curios it deletes 6 rows instead of 4 because of ties? Any idea to avoid that

Comment: @VaibhavSingh that would be using `iris %>% filter(!Sepal.Length %in%  head(sort(unique(Sepal.Length), decreasing = FALSE), 4) )`, but you said it is not that useful

Comment: it is extremely useful, please pardon me if it came out like that. I am going to use both of the solution as per situation. Thank you. Extremely helpful

Comment: @VaibhavSingh or you may do `iris %>% filter(!dense_rank(-Sepal.Length) %in% 1:4)`

Comment: @VaibhavSingh I didn't meant that.  I was thinking that for your specific case, it may be a bit too restrictive

Comment: Only issue is that I do not have way to handle ties, ideally I want to remove only 4 rows both the dplyr option removes six rows

Comment: @VaibhavSingh then you can use `row_number` insteda of `dense_rank` (updated

Answer (score 2):

The main reason your first approach is not working is because of the order or arguments to `top_n`. Consider:

```
args(top_n)
#function (x, n, wt) 
#NULL
```

Recall that the `%>%` operator passes the left hand side as the *first* argument of the right hand side. Therefore, `Septal.Length` becomes the second and `4` becomes the 3rd.

Thus, the column you want to use to filter on needs to be last or specifically defined:

```
iris %>%
   top_n(wt=Sepal.Length,4)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#1          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
#2          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
#3          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0 virginica
#4          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0 virginica
#5          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3 virginica

#Altenative
iris %>%
  top_n(4,Sepal.Length)
```

Please refer to @akrun's answer for your second question.